# Subset a list and retain original length with blank missing values

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following list:

```
month_list=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan']
```

Starting with the first value, I want to select every '4th' value and I achieve this as follows:-

```
quarter_list=month_list[0::3]

print(quarter_list)

['Jan', 'Apr', 'Jul', 'Oct', 'Jan']
```

However, I want a list of original list length with blank values filled in place of unwanted data.
Expected output as follows:-

```
print(quarter_list_expected')
['Jan','','','Apr','','','Jul','','','Oct','','','Jan']
```

Please suggest the way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comprehension will do, using `enumerate` and testing mod 3 on the index:

```
quarter_list = ['' if i % 3 else m for i, m in enumerate(month_list)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
quarter_list_expected = [month if month in quarter_list else '' for month in month_list]
```

Output:

```
['Jan', '', '', 'Apr', '', '', 'Jul', '', '', 'Oct', '', '', 'Jan']
```